# Timer function on ajax generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web page which displays a live twitter feed.

The content is a set of links having class mlink.

If I click on a link, it displays the particular tweet details using a jquery tooltip fired on an OnClick event - This works perfectly. Script 1

the content is continuously updated every few seconds using Ajax on a php script - Again this works perfectly. Script 2

I have a third script on the page which does the same thing as script 1 but instead of a click event, it uses a timer. Again, this works perfectly on the content which was loaded on page load, **BUT does NOT work on the ajax generated content.** Script 3

I understand I have to use a delegate  instead of $(document).ready for this to work. But as I have very limited JQuery knowledge, I do not know how to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is script 3

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(function() {

    //Get ids of all links with class mlink and insert into array
    var IDs = [];
    $(".mlink").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });

    //Select random element from array
    var item = IDs[Math.floor(Math.random()*IDs.length)];

    //Get attributes of item
    var xid = $('#'+item).attr('xid');
    var yid = $('#'+item).attr('yid');
    var zid = $('#'+item).attr('zid');
    var tcon = $('#'+item).attr('tcon');
    var imgcon = $('#'+item).attr('imgcon');
    var dtscon = $('#'+item).attr('dtscon');

    //Generate HTML
    var htmlstr = '';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'<div style="display: none; max-width: 600px; position: absolute;" class="ttx" id="'+xid+'">';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'<div class="row">';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'<div class="large-3 columns xicon" id="'+yid+'">';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'<img src="'+imgcon+'" />';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'</div>';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'<div class="large-9 columns xtcon" id="'+zid+'">';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'<h2>'+tcon+'</h2>';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'</div>';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'</div>';
    var htmlstr = htmlstr+'</div>';

    //Close any open tooltip
    $('.ttx').remove();

    //Append Generated content to body
    $('body').append(htmlstr);

    //Position Generated Content
    $('#'+xid).center();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#'+xid).center();
    });

    //Show Generated Content
    $('#'+xid).toggle(function(){
        $('#'+zid).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    //Remove tooltip
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.ttx').remove();
    }, 1000 * 60 * 0.2);
}, 1000 * 60 * 0.1); 
});

//Centering function
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +
    $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) +
    $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or plnkr demo to show your code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your events are either attached on elements that do not get replaced by Ajax generated content or ensure you (re-)attach those events after you generated your content via Ajax.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. My problem is that my event is simply time and NOT some thing like "click". My specific question is how to write a delegate which uses time for eventType

Comment: hmm hard to tell.. code looks OK, second setInterval should be a setTimeout I guess; you'll need to debug.. check the content of the array IDs you produce if it holds new items or not.